# Swift iOS 8 float into textField

Tags: swift, textfield, ios8

How can I put a Float into textField in swift , here is how I did it with an Int

oneValue, twoValue, threeValue are textFields

```
   @IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {
    var value1 = oneValue.text .toInt()
    value1 = value1! * 5
    var value2 = twoValue.text .toInt()
    value2 = value2! * 3
    var value3 = threeValue.text .toInt()
    value3 = value3! * 8


    totalTextField.text = " $ \(value1! + value2! + value3!)"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in syntax between the types.  If you want to know how to format floating points, there are at least two good posts on SO for that.  In short though, and in a playground:

```
let one:Float = 1.0, two:Float = 2.0, three:Float = 3.0
let s = "\(one + two + three)"
s // 6.0
```

Comment: chrisco Thanks for the help been trying to figure this out for awhile